# Get CST current date at 00:00:00 time in java

Tags: java, date, cron, scheduler, zone

I need the current date in following format at 00:00:00 CST time.

Like say current date is July 9 2021 Then I need that date along with 00:00:00 time.

**Expected Output:**

`Fri Jul 09 00:00:00 CST 2021`

**Current code:**

```
LocalDateTime date= LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MIN);
Date dayStart= Date.from(date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

**Output of CurrentCode:** `Fri Jul 09 00:00:00 UTC 2021`

Current code picking servertime /GMT which is 5hrs ahead of CST.

**Example:** `09AM GMT is 14 CST/2PM CST`

I have tried to set calendar to 00:00:00 and setTimeZone to America/New_York. But while am returning output as calendar.getTime() give some other time rather than giving CST 00:00:00.

**Tried :** `@scheduled(zone="America/New_york" )` --Not Working.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you mixing old/outdated API with the modern one? You take the current date and time (**without** explicitly considering the time zone) by means of `java.time.LocalDateTime.now()` but use a legacy compatibility method to get a `java.util.Date` in the end.

Comment: It should work. I ran this code on my local machine and it worked fine.  https://www.ideone.com/3jVfUh. If you are running on the local machine you can verify this by changing your machine timezone.

Comment: actually its picking the server time which is UTC/GMT. I need convert that GMT to CST. Local time it will work. While deploying the code its not working.

Comment: working in enhancement part. Thats why there is a old code. Repository is picking only 00:00:00 as a Date object. Thats why Date is at end

Comment: America/New_york is not CST. The systemDefault is not CST. You have combined two different time api without using zone / offset information. So many things to check here. Can you first set your ZoneId to `America/Chicago` (which is CDT right now) and then do the exact same thing that you are doing?

Comment: How do you push new values into your repository? Does it take formatted `String`s or `java.util.Date`s?

Comment: @deHaar Its using Date not String

Answer (score 2):

There are two good answers. My suggestion only differs in the detail (which is where the devil is, according to some).

First of all you should avoid using the `Date` class if you can. You are already using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, (`LocalDateTime`, `LocalTime`, `ZoneId`). You are getting all the functionality that you need from java.time. So I am assuming that you are only converting to `Date` because you need a `Date` for some legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now.

```
    Instant startOfDay = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(startOfDay);
    
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

`.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)` throws away the time part of the `ZonedDateTime`, usually leaving us with 00:00:00 on the same day in the same time zone.

Edit:

> I want America Chicago time CDT

Running the above code with the default time zone of the JVM set to America/Chicago gave:

> Mon Jul 12 00:00:00 CDT 2021

Getting the right `Date` value and getting the expected printed output are two different things since `Date.toString()` picks the default time zone of the JVM and uses it for rendering the string to be returned. This behaviour may give surprises. There is no way to persuade `Date.toString()` to use a different time zone, so the above output only comes through setting the default time zone.

Original text: There are a lot of time zones referred to as CST and there’s no way I can be sure which one you intended (and i believe that the comments stating that America/New_York is not one of them are correct). However, the only one that I could persuade the old-fashioned `Date` class to abbreviate CST was China Standard Time. Running the above code in Asia/Shanghai time zone gave this output:

> Sat Jul 10 00:00:00 CST 2021

It looks right to me. Since you asked your question it has become Saturday 10th in China Standard Time time zone.

Any time zone will work for getting the right `Date` value, the start of the day in that time zone. You also wanted an abbreviation of `CST` in the printed output. Time zones that did not work for this include:

- Australia/Adelaide time zone. Output was `Sat Jul 10 00:00:00 ACST 2021`. So even though Australian Central Standard Time is sometimes abbreviated just CST, `Date` chose ACST.
- America/Havana. Cuba uses Cuba Daylight Time at this time of year, so CDT is output.
- America/Winnipeg and American/Chicago.  North American Central Time uses daylight saving time too, so here too CDT is output.

In any case, you know which time zone you intended, so I am leaving to you to pick.

Comment: Liked `.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)`

Comment: Yeah, @ArvindKumarAvinash, IMHO an advantage is we need to specify the time zone only once so there’s no risk of an inconsistent time zone specification by mistake (or by the default time zone being changed under our feet while our code i running).

Comment: I want America Chicago time CDT @OleV.V. I checked with Instant startOfDay = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    .toInstant();
  Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(startOfDay);
  LOGGER.info("stackoverflow date check-->"+oldfashionedDate); But not giving expected output

Comment: You need to set the default time zone of your JVM in order to obtain that output. Please see my edit. @sangeetha

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change the timezone is to use System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/New_York"); in Java NOTE:: America/New_York is not CST

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

class DateAndTimeZoneFormatter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/New_York");

        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MIN);
        Date dayStart = Date.from(date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        System.out.println(dayStart);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a `ZonedDateTime` with a specific `ZoneId`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the zone to be used
    ZoneId americaChicago = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
    // then take the date of today
    ZonedDateTime nowInChicago = ZonedDateTime.of(
                                    LocalDate.now(),  // today
                                    LocalTime.MIN,    // start of day
                                    americaChicago    // zone
                                 );
    // define an output format
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss")
                                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                                    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)
                                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                                    .appendPattern("uuuu")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    // then print the formatted String representation
    System.out.println(nowInChicago.format(dtf));
}
```

This outputs

```
Fri Jul 09 00:00:00 CDT 2021
```

Downsides:

- this won't fully match your expected output due to `CST` not being applied because it is daylight saving time. Therefore, `CDT` will be the output.
- taking a `Date.from` this `ZonedDateTime.toInstant()` will affect the values:

Applying these two lines

```java
Date sameNowInChicago = Date.from(nowInChicago.toInstant());
System.out.println(sameNowInChicago);
```

will output

```
Fri Jul 09 07:00:00 CEST 2021
```

**on my machine** because it is configured to have a `ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")`, which will be taken into account when printing a `java.util.Date`.
*CEST* ⇒ *Central European Summer Time*.

Comment: yeah while converting into Date the time changed. But it will ony accept Fri Jul 09 00:00:00 CDT 2021

Comment: Sorry, @sangeetha, that’s not perfectly clear. The point in time does not change by converting to date. When deHaar’s `Date` prints with the time `07:00:00`, it’s only because of their time zone. The value of the `Date` is correct. `07:00:00 CEST` is the same point in time as `00:00:00 CDT` (North American Central Daylight Time)).